# How to efficiently resample a DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas has a `resample` method on a series/dataframe but there seems no way to resample a `DatetimeIndex` on its own?

Concretely, I have a daily `Datetimeindex` with possibly missing dates and I want to resample it at an hourly freq but only including days which are in the original daily index.

Is there a better way than my attempt below?

```python
In [56]: daily_index = pd.period_range('01-Jan-2017', '31-Jan-2017', freq='B').asfreq('D')

In [57]: daily_index
Out[57]: 
PeriodIndex(['2017-01-02', '2017-01-03', '2017-01-04', '2017-01-05',
             '2017-01-06', '2017-01-09', '2017-01-10', '2017-01-11',
             '2017-01-12', '2017-01-13', '2017-01-16', '2017-01-17',
             '2017-01-18', '2017-01-19', '2017-01-20', '2017-01-23',
             '2017-01-24', '2017-01-25', '2017-01-26', '2017-01-27',
             '2017-01-30', '2017-01-31'],
            dtype='int64', freq='D')

In [58]: daily_index.shape
Out[58]: (22,)

In [59]: hourly_index = pd.DatetimeIndex([]).union_many(
    ...:     pd.date_range(day.to_timestamp('H','S'), day.to_timestamp('H','E'), freq='H')
    ...:     for day in daily_index
    ...: )

In [60]: hourly_index
Out[60]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2017-01-02 00:00:00', '2017-01-02 01:00:00',
               '2017-01-02 02:00:00', '2017-01-02 03:00:00',
               '2017-01-02 04:00:00', '2017-01-02 05:00:00',
               '2017-01-02 06:00:00', '2017-01-02 07:00:00',
               '2017-01-02 08:00:00', '2017-01-02 09:00:00',
               ...
               '2017-01-31 14:00:00', '2017-01-31 15:00:00',
               '2017-01-31 16:00:00', '2017-01-31 17:00:00',
               '2017-01-31 18:00:00', '2017-01-31 19:00:00',
               '2017-01-31 20:00:00', '2017-01-31 21:00:00',
               '2017-01-31 22:00:00', '2017-01-31 23:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=528, freq=None)

In [61]: 22*24
Out[61]: 528

In [62]: %%timeit
    ...: hourly_index = pd.DatetimeIndex([]).union_many(
    ...:     pd.date_range(day.to_timestamp('H','S'), day.to_timestamp('H','E'), freq='H')
    ...:     for day in daily_index
    ...: )
100 loops, best of 3: 13.7 ms per loop
```

**UPDATE:**

I went with a slight variation of @NTAWolf's answer which has similar performance but won't reorder the input dates in case they're not sorted

```python
def resample_index(index, freq):
    """Resamples each day in the daily `index` to the specified `freq`.

    Parameters
    ----------
    index : pd.DatetimeIndex
        The daily-frequency index to resample
    freq : str
        A pandas frequency string which should be higher than daily

    Returns
    -------
    pd.DatetimeIndex
        The resampled index

    """
    assert isinstance(index, pd.DatetimeIndex)
    start_date = index.min()
    end_date = index.max() + pd.DateOffset(days=1)
    resampled_index = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq=freq)[:-1]
    series = pd.Series(resampled_index, resampled_index.floor('D'))
    return pd.DatetimeIndex(series.loc[index].values)
```

```python
In [184]: %%timeit
     ...: hourly_index3 = pd.date_range(daily_index.start_time.min(), 
     ...:                               daily_index.end_time.max() + 1, 
     ...:                               normalize=True, freq='H')
     ...: hourly_index3 = hourly_index3[hourly_index3.floor('D').isin(daily_index.start_time)]
100 loops, best of 3: 2.97 ms per loop

In [185]: %timeit resample_index(daily_index.to_timestamp('D','S'), freq='H')
100 loops, best of 3: 2.93 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
|             Method              |  Time   | Relative |
|---------------------------------|---------|----------|
| OP's updated approach           | 1.31 ms |  17.6 %  |
| Generate daterange, np.in1d     | 1.75 ms |  23.5 %  |
| Generate daterange, Series.isin | 1.90 ms |  25.5 %  |
| Resample with dummy Series      | 4.37 ms |  58.7 %  |
| OP's initial approach           | 7.45 ms | 100.0 %  |
```

### Update 2: Generate daterange, `np.in1d`

Again, @IanS inspired more optimisation! This is a little less readable, but a bit faster:

```
%%timeit -r 10
hourly_index4 = pd.date_range(daily_index.start_time.min(), 
                              daily_index.end_time.max() + pd.DateOffset(days=1), 
                              normalize=True, freq='H')
overlap = np.in1d(np.array(hourly_index4.values, dtype='datetime64[D]'),
                  np.array(daily_index.start_time.values, dtype='datetime64[D]'))
hourly_index4 = hourly_index4[overlap]

1000 loops, best of 10: 1.75 ms per loop
```

Here, speedups are gained by converting the values of both Series to the same numpy datetime kind (flooring `hourly_index` in the process). Passing `.values` to numpy sped it up a little bit.

### Update 1: Generate daterange, `Series.isin`

Faster approach than the initial bid, inspired by @IanS's approach: Generate daterange for the complete range of dates in your data, per hour, and select only those entries that match existing dates in your data:

```
%%timeit
hourly_index3 = pd.date_range(daily_index.start_time.min(), 
                              # The following line should use 
                              # +pd.DateOffset(days=1) in place of +1
                              # but is left as is to show the option.
                              daily_index.end_time.max() + 1, 
                              normalize=True, freq='H')
hourly_index3 = hourly_index3[hourly_index3.floor('D').isin(daily_index.start_time)]

100 loops, best of 3: 1.9 ms per loop
```

which cuts off about 75% processing time.

### Original answer: Resample with dummy Series

Using a dummy series, you can avoid the looping. On my computer, it cuts off about 40% of the run time.

I get the following time for your approach:

```
In [14]: %%timeit -o -r 10
   ....: hourly_index = pd.DatetimeIndex([]).union_many(   
   ....:     pd.date_range(day.to_timestamp('H','S'), day.to_timestamp('H','E'), freq='H')
   ....:     for day in daily_index
   ....: )
   ....: 
100 loops, best of 10: 7.45 ms per loop
```

And for the faster approach:

```
In [13]: %%timeit -o -r 10
s = pd.Series(0, index=daily_index)
s = s.resample('H').last()
s = s[s.index.start_time.floor('D').isin(daily_index.start_time)]
hourly_index2 = s.index.start_time
   ....: 
100 loops, best of 10: 4.37 ms per loop
```

Note that we don't really care about the value put into the series; here I just default to `int`.

The expression `s.index.start_time.floor('D').isin(daily_index.start_time)` gives us a boolean vector for which values in `s.index` that match days in `daily_index`.

Comment: Bonus points for using `floor` - I'm reasonably familiar with the pandas api but that's a new one for me!

Comment: I wonder if `hourly_index3.date` wouldn't be faster than `hourly_index3.floor('D')`.

Comment: @IanS, your comment led me to find a faster approach by directly using the numpy types :-)
`hourly_index3.date` can't be plugged directly, as it is a numpy array, which does not have `.isin`. Also, it has `dtype=object`, which is not efficient for our purposes. Hence the modifications seen in Update 2 above.

Comment: @DaveHirschfeld That is a really nice solution. Also nice with `pd.DateOffset(days=1)`; that's a new one for me! It feels much safer than just using +1 and hoping the data type is right.

Comment: @NTAWolf, nice! Too bad I can't upvote your answer, I already did yesterday :)

Answer (score 5):

Another option would be to generate the hourly index directly, and remove non-business days afterwards:

```
hourly_index = pd.date_range('01-Jan-2017', '31-Jan-2017', freq='H')
hourly_index = hourly_index[hourly_index.dayofweek < 5]
```

---

Performance comparison:

- OP's solution: `10 loops, best of 3: 44.2 ms per loop`
- EdChum's solution: `1000 loops, best of 3: 1.46 ms per loop`
- My solution: `1000 loops, best of 3: 598 µs per loop`

Comment: You should add the timing of the OP's attempt to compare timings due to differing machine speeds +1

Comment: `pd.date_range('01-Jan-2017', '31-Jan-2017', freq='H')` ends at `Timestamp('2017-01-31 00:00:00', offset='H')`, meaning that we don't capture the hours of the final day in the range. Increment by one :-)

Comment: The business day was just to simulate a non-contiguous series. In general the missing days may be random so the post-filtering operation wouldn't be quite as simple as that